# Unintentional multiple installations of MySQL on OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, navicat

How can I find all installations of MySQL on my Mac to remove them and then start fresh.

I have symptoms indicating multiple installations of MySQL on my MacBookPro (used for development).  Specifically, Navicat, a GUI for db management, connects and shows one set of databases, and PHP code that I write works on databases that don't show up in Navicat.

Additionally, if I stop MySQL via System Preferences, my code no longer works (that's expected) BUT Navicat still can connect to databases.

Anyone have a clue how I can dig myself out?

Comment: This will help you: http://tomkeur.net/39/how-to-remove-mysql-completely-mac-os-x-leopard.html